# Difference between interface and service (networking)?

Tags: networking, service, interface, protocols

So, peers communicate using a protocol.
Protocols communicate using interfaces which define primitive operations.
Are services the same as interfaces?

> A service is a set of primitives (operations) that a layer provides to the layer above it. -*Computer Networks* by Tanenbaum & Wheterall.

Or does it relate to interfaces in some way? Is it more concrete (can it only be used between some layers)?

> A service relates to an interface between two layers. -*Computer Networks* by Tanenbaum & Wheterall.

Answer (score 2):

Lets break it down Step by Step be patient

1. The function of each layer in computer networking architecture is to provide services (i,e., setting up connection,delivering information) to the layer above it.
2. The active elements in each layer are often called entities. An entity can be a software entity (such as a process), or a hardware entity (such as an intelligent I/O chip).
3. The entities in layer n implement a service used by layer n+1. In this case layer n called the service provider and layer n+1 is called the service user.
4. Layer n may use the services of layer n-1 in order to provide its service. It may offer several classes of service for example, fast/expensive communication and slow/cheap communication.
5. Services are available at SAPs (Service Access Points). The layer n SAPs are the places where layer n+1 can access the services offered. Each SAP has an address that uniquely identifies it.
   [image: Layer And Interface]
6. In order for two layers to exchange information, there has to be an agreed upon set of rules about the interface.
7. At a typical interface, the layer n+1 entity passes an IDU (Interface Data Unit) to the layer n entity through the SAP.
8. The IDU consists of an SDU (Service Data Unit) and some control information.
9. The SDU is the information passes across the network to the peer entity and then up to layer n+1 ( in peer).
10. The control information is needed to help the lower layer so its job (e.g., the number of bytes in the SDU) but is not part of the data itself.

****Conclusion** : ** Services are set of operations and Interface provides a way to implement them.
Hope that helps ,Thank You.

Answer (score -2):

Hope your doing well.

```
    □ Services : 
        ® is a set of primitives (operations ) that a layer provide to the layer above it .
        ® each layer perform some service to above layer 
        ® Define layer's semantics 
        ® Service relates to an interface  between layers 
            ® Upper layer is service use
            ® Lower layer is service provider 
    □ Primitives:
        ® Set of operations that a service in some layer provide 
    □ Interface
        ® Tells the process above it how to access it 
        ® Specifies what are the parameters and what result to expect 
    □ protocols
        ® The layers own business 
        ® A layer can use any protocol it wants , as long as it gets the job
```

Ex: in a programming language:
Service is like abstract data type , it defines operations that can be performed  on an object , but does not specify HOW the operation is implemented .

Comment: Don't use code formstting for text that isn't code. Answer is mostly nonsense.